# Number of ways to arrange Americans,Frenchs,Germans and Russians around a circular table

Tags: permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can $3$ Americans, $4$ Germans, $2$ Frenchmen, and
>   $3$ Russians sit around a circular table if those of the same country
>   sit together ?

**What I've tried**

I've first considered the case where I had one people from each of those countries.

In this case I would have $3!$ ,now for every of these combinations I can add up chairs for the other people from the same country ,yelding:

$3!3!4!2!3!=10368$

However I don't know if that's correct since I didn't find any solutions on the Internet. Also is there another way to look at the problem above ?

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, but only as long as you don't treat everyone rotating around the table as separate solutions. If you do, then multiply by 12 i.e. the total number of positions.

I can't think of any other obvious ways of thinking of the problem.